# Operator "&&" cannot be applied MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to create counter method where it counts the number of jobs stopped at each location. I took an attempt at it as seen below but I get the following error:

> Error  1   Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'JobTracker.Models.Job'  D:\C# Web Application\JobTracker-Dev2 FINAL\JobTracker\Controllers\JobController.cs 126 46  JobTracker

I know this has something to do with `boolean` and an `Int` comparison but I don't know how I can resolve it in the current state it is in

```
public int Stopped()
{
    int Stopped = db.Jobs.Where(x => x.Status == "Stopped" && x => x.LocationID == 1).Count();
    return Stopped;
}
```

Also is there an easy way of keeping the counts all in one method. I have about 20 of these separate methods and I'd love to have them all in one method, then I can initialize that method and call each variable when needed

```
 public void Stopped()
{

    int HBAStop = db.Jobs.Where(x => x.Status == "Stopped" && x.LocationID == 1).Count();
    int CRStop =  db.Jobs.Where(x => x.Status == "Stopped" && x.LocationID == 2).Count();
    int MAStop =  db.Jobs.Where(x => x.Status == "Stopped" && x.LocationID == 3).Count();
    int QCStop =  db.Jobs.Where(x => x.Status == "Stopped" && x.LocationID == 4).Count();
    int LTStop =  db.Jobs.Where(x => x.Status == "Stopped" && x.LocationID == 5).Count();
    int PTStop =  db.Jobs.Where(x => x.Status == "Stopped" && x.LocationID == 6).Count();
    int SPStop =  db.Jobs.Where(x => x.Status == "Stopped" && x.LocationID == 7).Count();

}
```

I hope that's clear, please let me know otherwise, I'll provide further information if needed.

Comment: `x.Status == "Stopped" && x.LocationID == 1`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove `x =>` as you have already mentioned at starting of where condition. That's It.

```
int Stopped = db.Jobs.Where(x => x.Status == "Stopped" && x.LocationID == 1).Count();
```

Comment: i presume there is no way of keeping them all within the one method? or do i need to create a new method for each location/stopped?

Comment: @goldeneye If I understood you correctly, You can use collection of List<int>  to get multiple status.

Comment: i updated the question there to show you what i mean, would i just need to add a collection in there?

Comment: @goldeneye Can you tell me how you are passing `Status` and `LocationID` to `Stopped()` function. Is it hard coded?

Comment: im using   private JobData db = new JobData(); at the top then querying it using db

Comment: @goldeneye That is fine. Are you using 1,2,3 as hard coded for `x.LocationID == 1`

Comment: yes, these are the location IDs in the SQL database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78168/discussion-between-rahul-nikate-and-goldeneye).

Answer (score 0):

you doing wrong what you need to do is:

```
int Stopped = db.Jobs.Where(x => x.Status == "Stopped" &&  x.LocationID == 1).Count();
```